# TextAlignment option broken in 13.1 on MacOS 13.0.1 (Confirmed with Wolfram)

Tags: bugs, user-interface

All of the cells in my notebooks that have the option TextAlignment->Center are broken since updating to MM 13.1.  It seems that the TextAlignment option does not update correctly as I change the window size.  Is anyone else having this issue?

The only way I can get it to update correctly is to show the underlying code and then close it. The video below demonstrates the issue and the rather annoying workaround.

I am using the default stylesheet.

[image]

Update --- Other users have confirmed this as a bug.  Note that TextAlignment fails in the Wolfram Documentation as well.  See the 1st example of the  "scope" section of TextAlignment in the documentation:

```
Do[Print[Style[a, TextAlignment -> a]], {a, -1, 1, .5}]
```

Window resizing does not auto-update the positions.  A temporary fix is to show and close the underlying code.

Comment: I can reproduce this with Input, Output, and DisplayFormula cells (and I'm also using 13.1). The other dozen or so cell formats I tested did auto-update on resize (didn't do exhaustive testing).

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2718797).

Comment: The 1st example in the "scope" section of `TextAlignment` documentation is good to verify that this is indeed an issue: `Do[Print[Style[a, TextAlignment -> a]], {a, -1, 1, .5}]` . I think this should have the bug tag

Comment: Has this been reported to Wolfram?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Wolfram.  They confirmed it is a bug.  They forwarded the information to their developers.  Hopefully, it's fixed sooner than later.

In the meantime... I put a button on my toolbar that temporarily fixes the issue in the current notebook until you resize the window again.

```
Button["Update", 
 Do[FrontEndExecute[
   FrontEndToken[InputNotebook[], "ToggleDynamicUpdating"]], {2}]]
```

I'm placing this button in all of my notebook toolbars but also my exported notebook toolbars for my students since they use the WolframPlayer.  The player has the same issue.